# Python. Accesing column indices in CSR format

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'm starting to work with python and CSR format.

I know that if I have an csr matrix properly initialized, and let's call it "conectivity", so, when I type

```
conectivity[14,:]
```

I will get as an answer something like this:

```
(0, 1)  1.0      
(0, 13) 1.0       
(0, 15) 1.0      
(0, 27) 1.0
```

What is the proper way to get this vector?

```
[ 1, 13, 15, 27 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`conectivity` is a matrix (not a subclass of `np.matrix`, but functionally similar).

```
conectivity[14,:]
```

is another 2d sparse matrix.  That's what your print shows

```
(0, 1)  1.0      
(0, 13) 1.0       
(0, 15) 1.0      
(0, 27) 1.0
```

`conectivity[14,:].toarray()` (or `.A` for short) will give you something like

```
[[0,1,0...1,0,1,....]]
```

a 2d array, with 1 row and lots of 0s.

`conectivity[14,:].data` is the `data` attribute of this matrix.

`conectivity[14,:].col` is the column index attribute.  I think this is what you want.

`conectivity[14,:].nonzero()` also gives the row and column values (of the nonzero terms).

---

I should add that while `nonzero` works for all sparse formats, `.col` only works for `coo` format (`coo` format does not implement this form of indexing).  For a `csr` matrix, `.indices` gives the column index values; and for a single row matrix this should be the desired array.  For multirow matrices `.indices` is more complicated.